# How to use <ios> or <android> elements in Nativescript Vue

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I would like to do this

```xml

```
  <android>
      <NavigationButton 
                 text="Go Back"
                 android.systemIcon="ic_menu_more"
                 @tap="$refs.drawer.nativeView.showDrawer()"/>
  </android>

  <ios>
     <ActionItem 
            text="Menu" 
            @tap="$refs.drawer.nativeView.showDrawer()" />
  </ios>
</ActionBar>
```

```

What is the best way to go about it ?

Answer (score 1):

As posted here https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue/issues/180#issuecomment-380844535

You can use these elements like you did, but the `ActionBar` is a bit different (hence why it doesn't work as you'd expect). What I've done in a project was to add

```js
// main.js
import { isAndroid, isIOS } from 'tns-core-modules/platform';
Vue.prototype.$isAndroid = isAndroid;
Vue.prototype.$isIOS = isIOS;
```

In template

```html
<ActionBar android.icon="ic_home" class="action-bar" title="Home">
         <NavigationButton 
                     v-if="$isAndroid"
                     text="Go Back"
                     android.systemIcon="ic_menu_more"
                     @tap="$refs.drawer.nativeView.showDrawer()"/>
         <ActionItem 
                v-else
                text="Menu" 
                @tap="$refs.drawer.nativeView.showDrawer()" />
</ActionBar>
```